# Can't install PHP extensions in Docker

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, php-extension

I'm trying to install PHP from Dockerfile on Raspberry Pi 4. I've got a simple code in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
LABEL maintainer="dev@chialab.io"

# Download script to install PHP extensions and dependencies
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq -y curl

#RUN install-php-extensions mysqli pdo_mysql zip

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

Everything goes well until the *'docker-php-ext-install'* part. Then the execution in the console stops, the last info is this:

```
Step 6/9 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
 ---> Running in 72e3ce3bad85
```

I also tried the *'install-php-extensions'* command in the Dockerfile instead, but with the same result.

**Another solution** I tried is to just run the following command in the console:

```
docker run --restart always -p 80:80 --name php -v "$PWD":/var/www -d php:7.4-apache
```

and install PHP extensions from inside of the container:

```
docker exec -it php /bin/bash
docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

But I'm getting the same issue: it just stops. By the way it seems strange to me that when I install the PHP with *'docker run'* then dozens of PHP extensions install but not mysqli, pdo_mysql or zip (I need these three).

In both cases I left it for over an hour but nothing moves, it just stops and nothing happens.

I tried to restart the docker daemon, clear cache, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from the **Dockerfile**. What i saw first is `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` added to almost each run command. Better to declare it once via `ARG` and forget about `yes/no`(example is below).

Another thing is amount of layers which are `RUN` instructions. Lets just say that the less the better. For more info read [best practicies](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers).

After simplifying and modifying your docker recipe and running a build command:

```
docker build --no-cache=true -t php-apache .
```

i received an error

`No package 'libzip' found`

After adding `libzip-dev` to recipe and running build command again we are getting an image.) I have also put **index.php** file in the same folder where Dockerfile is with `phpinfo()` function just to check if extensions were installed(docker file with changes and command to run a container you can find below)

`docker run --name php-apache -d -p 8181:80 php-apache`

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync

# much simplier to use ARG instead of specifiying it each time on the FLY before each install command
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# 1 RUN = 1 layer, more memory to consume. Better to group everthing under one layer as much as possible
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mysqli zip \
    && a2enmod rewrite
# this line can be removed if you don't want to check php extensions
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# this line also can be removed if you don't want to check php extensions
COPY index.php .
```